# Get rid of extra HTMl tags using jQuery

Tags: html, tags, addition

When am using dynamic content its creating extra tags how can i get rid of extra HTMl tags using jQuery

For examole :

```
<p>
<figure>
<div><img src="image.png"/></div>
</figure>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
```

in this above code i need to get rid of p tag before figure tag & add after figure tag

Comment: it's not creating extra tags, it's `<figure>` that is inserted in the wrong place, inside the `<p>`

Comment: Which dynamic/server-side programming language are you using??

Comment: Content getting through XML